# How to join some data to all data

Tags: sql, join, select

I have 3 tables  Contact, EmailAddress, PhoneNumbers

I want my query to return all contacts that are active

Then I want to get their email address and phone numbers if they exist but if they don't I still want the contact.

Additionally if their JobCategory is "caretaker" or "Technician" I only want to see their work phone number, otherwise I want all their phone numbers, Ideally as in there own columns

FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, WorkPhone, CellPhone, HomePhone

This query returns only active contacts that have a work phone number , email address and are in the specified JobCategory

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.JobCategory, e.EmailAddress, PhoneNumber
FROM Contacts AS c 

LEFT JOIN EmailAddress AS e ON c.ContactsPK = e.ContactFK
LEFT JOIN PhoneNumbers AS pWork ON c.ContactsPK = pWork.ContactFK 

WHERE
    c.Active = 1 AND 
    pWork.PhoneType = 'Work' AND 
    ( 
        c.JobCategory = 'Caretaker' OR 
        c.JobCategory = 'Technician'
    )

ORDER by c.JobCategory
```

How can I modify this query to show all active contacts and only return the work phone numbers for contact with the specified jobCategory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the filtering condition on `'Work'` to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.JobCategory, e.EmailAddress, 
       PhoneNumber
FROM Contacts c LEFT JOIN
     EmailAddress e
     ON c.ContactsPK = e.ContactFK LEFT JOIN
     PhoneNumbers pWork
     ON c.ContactsPK = pWork.ContactFK AND pWork.PhoneType = 'Work'    
WHERE c.Active = 1 AND 
      c.JobCategory IN ('Caretaker', c.JobCategory = 'Technician')
ORDER by c.JobCategory
```

Comment: This really help me get in the right direction I was able to get exactly what i needed, thank you